# Error on mouse down when using d3-brush: Cannot read property 'touches' of null

Tags: angular, d3.js

I'm using D3 (with help of d3-ng2-service https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service) in angular4's component and everything was fine and working as intended but... There is a strange error started to appear when I try to select region to zoom:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'touches' of null
    at SVGGElement.started (brush.js:291)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (on.js:27)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3924)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at SVGGElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:486)
```

It looks like brush.js does not receive event object, but I can't figure out what can cause such situation. The code that defines brush:

```
let mouseGRect = this.svg.append('g')
     .attr('class', 'brush');

let brush = d3.brushX()
     .on('start', () => {
     })
     .on('brush', () => {
     })
     .on('end', () => {
     });

mouseGRect.call(brush);
```

d3 modules installed:

```
d3-array          
d3-axis           
d3-brush          
d3-chord          
d3-collection     
d3-color          
d3-dispatch       
d3-drag           
d3-dsv            
d3-ease           
d3-force          
d3-format         
d3-geo            
d3-hierarchy      
d3-interpolate    
d3-ng2-service    
d3-path           
d3-polygon        
d3-quadtree       
d3-queue          
d3-random         
d3-scale          
d3-selection      
d3-selection-multi
d3-time           
d3-time-format    
d3-timer          
d3-transition     
d3-voronoi
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem. Somehow part of d3-* modules were installed in node_modules of my app and some in node_modules of d3-ng2-service. No idea why npm did this and how they conflicted with each other but after reinstalling of d3-ng2-service errors gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem a couple of time and the answer from @Dimanoid has helped. I thought I'd add a note for finding which d3 packages are the offending ones.

None of the node_modules/d3* folders should have their own node_modules folder. From project base directory on linux/mac:

```
ls -al node_modules/d3*/node_modules

gave me:
d3-request/node_modules:
.bin
d3-dsv     <----that is the offender
```

If this finds any sub folders, you can try to move them to your base node_modules directory:

```
mv node_modules/d3*/node_modules/* node_modules
```

Then remove any that didn't get moved (because they may already exist in node_modules):

```
rm node_modules/d3*/node_modules/*
```

Comment: Thanks! Wonder what causes some of the D3 packages to have their own `node_modules` directory???

Comment: I found that in my `package-lock.json` file, under `"d3"` there were some `dependencies` listed there. After I removed the `dependencies` for `d3` in `package-lock.json` this problem was resolved (in addition to removing the nested `node_modules` dir like suggested above).

Comment: Ah nice, that makes sense. Good find.

Answer (score 1):

d3-brush 1.0.6 has a [hard dependency on d3-selection 1.0.0](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/8aed2b3cec0d5cb1bd64aaa49f0128e392efdd2e/package.json#L35).

When you're using a higher version of d3-selection npm or yarn will install version 1.0.0  of d3-selection into node_modules/d3-brush/node_modules/d3-selection.

To fix this, add a resolution for d3-selection to your package.json. This way only one version of d3-selection will be installed.

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "d3-brush": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-selection": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "d3-selection": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```